# factanal in Base R and handling of NAs

Tags: r, function, statistics, factor-analysis

I have a `data.frame` called `D` shown [HERE](https://github.com/rnorouzian/i/blob/master/SLI.csv). I'm want to use the `factanal` function in base R on the first `8` columns of `D`.

I'm wondering, however, why I get the following error: `'x' must contain finite values only` while I have set for `NA`s to be removed?

```
D <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/i/master/SLI.csv", h = T)

pre <- D[1:8] # separate first 8 columns

factanal(pre, factors = 1, scores = "reg", na.action = na.omit) 

# Error in cov.wt(z) : 'x' must contain finite values only
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation states that the `na.action` argument applies only if a formula is passed as `x`.  If you want to pass a `data.frame` with missing values you need to subset it.

```
pre <- D[complete.cases(D[1:8]),1:8] 

factanal(pre, factors = 1, scores = "reg" ) 

Call:
factanal(x = pre, factors = 1, scores = "reg")

Uniquenesses:
 Q1_a  Q2_a  Q3_a  Q4_a  Q5_a  Q6_a  Q7_a  Q8_a 
0.645 0.547 0.801 0.556 0.254 0.280 0.996 0.915 

Loadings:
     Factor1
Q1_a 0.596  
Q2_a 0.673  
Q3_a 0.446  
Q4_a 0.666  
Q5_a 0.863  
Q6_a 0.848  
Q7_a        
Q8_a 0.292  

               Factor1
SS loadings      3.006
Proportion Var   0.376

Test of the hypothesis that 1 factor is sufficient.
The chi square statistic is 17.83 on 20 degrees of freedom.
The p-value is 0.599
```

Or same result:

```
factanal(as.formula(paste0("~", paste0(names(D[1:8]), collapse = " + "))), data = D, na.action = "na.omit", factors = 1, scores = "reg" )
```